# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.mail.javamail.SmartMimeMessage

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, mail-sender

I'm getting below error while sending email from a java web project.
IDE: **eclipse** 
Java version: **openjdk version "1.8.0_212-3-redhat"** 
Spring version: **5.1.6.RELEASE**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.mail.javamail.SmartMimeMessage
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.createMimeMessage(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:373)
at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:365)
```

Following is the filtered dependency tree for mail
[image]

I have tried the following:-

- Maven install
- Deleted existing tomcat server and added a new server in eclipse.
- changed local repository of maven for fresh dependencies download.
- deleted the project from eclipse workspace and deleted all eclipse settings and configuration file/folder then re-import the existing maven project
- checked for `org.springframework.mail.javamail.SmartMimeMessage` class in the `spring-context-support-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar` at project explorer as well as on file system
  [image]

> NOTE: This was a working code but suddenly I'm getting this error now.
>  
>   No Compilation error in project and war is also able to successfully deployed on the server.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml? Where do you deploy your war? How do you run it?

Comment: Im deploying the war on Tomcat server in Eclipse.

Comment: Do you use the same jdk for Tomcat? Did you check that the jar is within your final war?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are package and class names collision among the following jars:-

- `jakarta.mail-api.jar`
- `javax.mail-api.jar`

**Problem cause**:
 Both jars will be part of the build and all classes will be added to the classpath.
Now the classes at the mercy of class load **order** and causing different version than expected.
**What triggers the problem**: 
I have run the maven with **force update of Snapshots/Releases**
Now the latest version `4.10.0` of the following dependency has  `jakarta.mail-api.jar` as an internal dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
    <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Solution**: Use only one jar. In may case `javax.mai-api.jar`
**What to change**: I have added the exclusion for the `jakarta.mail-api.jar` in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
    <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

> **Key learning point** : Use of Release/Snapshot version in pom.xml **can lead** to dependency conflicts and issues like `NoClassDefFoundError` if you run the maven with option **force update of Snapshots/Releases**